# How to restrict some table view cells that not show swipe delete functionality in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView in which 5 types of cells and my problem is I have to perform the swipe gesture functionality on a specific one cell.

Comment: You can do this by same condition as you do in `cellForRow` to load 5 types of cell.

Answer (score 2):

You can use canEditRowAt function to specify editable row.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        if (indexPath.row == 0){
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a UITableViewDelegate Method **canRowEditAt** where you can specify whether the row is editable or not on the basic of indexPath.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    if (indexPath.row == YOUR-EDITABLE-ROW-INDEXPATH){
        return true
    } else { // YOUR-NON-EDITABLE-ROW-INDEXPATH
        return false
    }
}
```